# Is it posible to make table view index start after search bar and make search bar fixed at the top?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, indexing, uisearchbar

I am new in iOS programing and i was studying UITableView. I have added a search bar with code to table view with index. But when i scroll down, search bar does not stay fixed on top of the screen also table index appears on search bar. How can I make search bar fixed on top and position table index starting below search bar?

Normal:
[image]
Scrolled: 
[image]
Desired:
[image]

Comment: dont put UISearchBar inside UITableView...keep it above the tableView..dont make it complex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be adding UISearchBar to UITbaleView's header that is why it goes up while you scroll the UITableView. You can take UISearchBar and UITableView from xib/nib and first put UISearchBar on top and below that put your UITableView may be you problem will be solved. If you need any help or guidance then you can tell me thanks :)